# PL/SQL : Efficient way to loop through a large table

Tags: sql, loops

I need to loop through a large table contains around 20k of rows. I tried using CURSOR and BULK COLLECT but it still takes very long time, around half to complete.

What is an efficient way in PL/SQL to loop through the large data set.

Comment: There is no other way if you have to use sql. Depending on task you might not need to use loop, this is the only way to improve performance.

Comment: show us your code so far - this may provide an indication of where the bottleneck is occurring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

normally looping through 20 k rows will be faster if you simply select them. The result can be manipulated while selecting, or you can manipulate the result in a temporary table or a table variable.

Comment: Thanks, I got an idea from your comments. Instead of looping i join it with the other table for data manipulation. :)